# Pass first element of jsp list to javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp, jstl, el

Ok so I'm trying to access the first element of a JSP list,

here's what I've come up with so far without any kind of luck:

`onclick="alert('<%=list[0]%>');"`

What's the best approach to access the first element and eventually to pass it to a javascript variable/function ?

I've heard that the `<% %>` tags are deprecated and some are suggesting relaying on JSTL/EL how can one use those without having to iterate the entire list and put a breakpoint for the iterators ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know before hand that you always need first element, you can remove and put the first element of list in request attribute itself. And then use request.getAttribute() 
 So no need to bother with JSTL. 

Or if you want to use EL, ${list[0]} should work.

Comment: actually I need the whole list on the page but I've also need the first element for further elaborations

Comment: yes, so I guess the above answer should be useful. You can try  el ${list[0]}